# button в цикле for

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте. Можно ли как-то

```
button1->visible= true;
button2->visible= true
button3->visible= true;
```

Записать в for? Так не получается

```
for (int i=1; i=3; i++) {
    button_i->visible=true;
}
```

Comment: @GALIAF95, Не забывайте принимать ответы на свои вопросы. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы кнопки создаете в run-time, то их можно запихнуть в контейнер и обращаться по индексу. Так же у формы должен быть контейнер.

Comment: можно пожалуйста по-проще объяснить, совсем недавно начал изучать vis c++

Comment: Да все просто. Только специфики VS я не знаю. Объясню на примере всеми забытого борландовского билдера или делфи. Если кнопки создаем кодом, то чтобы к ним обращаться по индексу, можно сделать так:

    ObjectList buttons = new ObjectList(); 

насчет контейнера не уверен - не помню уже точно, что да как, но смысл, думаю, понятен.
Если же создавать интерфейс вытягиванием элементов на форму, то у формы тоже есть некий контейнер, но там хранятся все элементы формы, поэтому, чтобы обратиться к какому-то элементу, надо сначала проверить, тот ли это элемент, а потом уже делать с ним что-то.

Comment: Самый простой контейнер -- массив указателей. Можно и контейнерные классы, как посоветовал @Romanoo, только в C++ этот путь после появления template'ов, и особенно stl не шибко популярен.

Comment: Нельзя как-то проще сделать, вместо button1 написать в цикле buttoni?
Или другой вопрос-как создать контнейнер run-time кнопкам?